# Turned Flask code into a package and getting TemplotNotFound error

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to turn my Flask code into a python package structure, but now that I've done that, when I try running the code, none of the HTML templates are found.

Here is the simplified structure of my current flask package. `run.py` is what I use to execute the Flask code. `routes.py` contains all my `@app.routes` where the HTML templates are called.

```
pipeline-ui/
   run.py
   pipeline_app/
       __init__.py
       routes.py
       models.py
       forms.py
       templates/
          pipeline-alt.html
```

The error message I get is: `TemplateNotFound: pipeline-alt.html`

**init.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager


app = Flask('__name__')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from pipeline_app import routes
```

**run.py:**

```
from pipeline_app import app 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**routes.py:**

```
from flask import url_for, render_template, request, flash, redirect
from pipeline_app import app
from pipeline_app.forms import InputForm, RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from pipeline_app.models import User, Post
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
from math import ceil
import json
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pipeline(): 
    form = InputForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            STACK_NAME = request.form['stack_name']

            # Store data in database for future use

            db.create_all()
            db_inputs = Post(stack_name=STACK_NAME)
            db.session.add(db_inputs)
            db.session.commit()

    return render_template('pipeline-alt.html', 
                            title='Pipeline Input', 
                            form=form,
                            STACK_NAME=STACK_NAME)
```

Comment: Update the code snippets with error what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `app = Flask('__name__')` to `app = Flask(__name__)`. Flask uses this parameter to find resources on the filesystem, so if it is not set correctly it will not be able to find your templates.